# Eclipse debug get exception which triggered debug mode

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse to do Android development.

If I run in debug mode, and my view code throws an exception in onCreateView eclipse will suspend the program, and I can then enter debug mode(Debug view) where I can se the call stack, and so on.

But I can't see the content of the exception which caused the problem. Right now my program is "suspended on inflateException" but I can't find the content of this inflateException. I would really like to see the cause variable in that exception, to find out what really caused the problem. Is that not possible?

My only work-around is not running in debug mode. Then the entire exception including cause will be printed to logcat.

Comment: Hit the run button a few times and it will show up in your logcat

Comment: But then I can't debug the problem anymore. I would like to be able to look at the stack and variables, after looking at the exception.

Answer (score 0):

look in your logcat window (a tab next to console) - that's where the stack trace is found.  To do this, you will need to "continue" (F8) until the debugger is actually done running.